# How to pass multiple component values to listener via ajax on button click

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have select box for list of account numbers, an input field to enter amount and a button to calculate total debit. I want to pass the amount and account values via ajax to  an event handler on click event.

Some how I am not able to pass the values entered to event handler.

Can someone suggest me, on how to do ?

My Xhtml:

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="RUIFW-from-el form-control"
id="fromAccountIndex" value="#{parentBean.fromAccountIndex}"
validator="#{tptValidator.validateFromAccount}">
<f:selectItems value="#{parentBean.fromAccountUIMap}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>


<h:inputText id="amount" name="amount" value="#{parentBean.amount}" class="RUIFW-form-el form-control" validator="#{tptValidator.validateAmount}"/>
```

Updated code:

```
<h:commandLink class="RUIFW-btn mar-lft-10 veraligntop">
<h:outputLabel value="#{GIBBundle.tpt_btn_calculate}"/>
<f:ajax execute="@this fromAccountIndex amount onclick" listener="#{parentBean.calculateClickedListener}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

My Bean Method

```
public void calculateClickedListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
                System.out.println("getFromAccountIndex()....."+getFromAccountIndex());
System.out.println("getAmount()....."+getAmount());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the `execute` attribute on the `f:ajax`. That attribute defaults to `@this`, and as a result, no other component will be processed and no values will be set. This is why the value bindings of your input components are likely to turn out null.

Set your `execute="@form"` or  `execute="@this fromAccountIndex amount"` to get the values updated in your bean

**Reference:**

- [`f:ajax` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/index.html)

Comment: I have updated the code in my post.. and it worked.. !!! Thanks for help..


But why are the validators are being called?? I don't want validators.. tptValidator.validateFromAccount and tptValidator.validateAmount to be called while handling event.. I have added these validators to be performed only on form submit.
I tried to skip validation by adding immediate="true" to command link.. but, then it doesn't pass the values to handler.

Thanks again in advance..

Comment: You want to submit the component and its values, but not validate it @RajeshRenke ?

Comment: yes..I don't want event handler to take care of validation .. on click on button and also when dropdown account value changes..